# How can I send JsonNode as an email attachment

Tags: java, json, jakarta-mail

How can I send JsonNode as an email attachment in java.email as a json file

```
 // Json node bit
 JsonNode requestBody = request().body().asJson();


 // Mail bit
 messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
 messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler( It should be passed here));
 messageBodyPart.setFileName("file.json");
 multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [`DataHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/activation/DataHandler.html) docs, it shows three constructors. One of them takes a [`DataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/activation/DataSource.html). The javamail API has an implementation called [`ByteArrayDataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html)

So, if you figure out how to serialize the `JsonNode` to a JSON `String`, you can do this:

```
String jsonStr = ...

new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(jsonStr.getBytes()));
```

Also, keep in mind that you should also set the MIME type of the attachment to `applicatio/json`.